# Optimizing away heap allocations

Tags: optimization, go

*When I am talking about Go, I am speaking about the gc compiler implementation.*

As far as I know, Go performs escape analysis.
The following idiom is seen pretty often in Go code:

```
func NewFoo() *Foo
```

Escape analysis would notice that Foo escapes NewFoo and allocate Foo on the heap.

This function could also be written as:

```
func NewFoo(f *Foo)
```

and would be used like

```
var f Foo
NewFoo(&f)
```

In this case, as long as f doesn't escape anywhere else, f could be allocated on the stack.

Now to my actual question.

Would it be possible for the compiler to optimize every `foo() *Foo` into `foo(f *Foo)`, even possibly over multiple levels where Foo is returned in each?

If not, in what kind of cases does this approach fail?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It was my impression that Go does inlining before escape analysis. So, are you *sure* NewFoo in your example allocates on the heap? I suspect it is inlined into the caller and if it doesn't escape the caller, it won't be heap allocated.

Comment: @Zan No, I am not sure, but now that you mentioned it I looked it up and Go does indeed do inlining. I am sorry, I had looked at three year old SO questions and go-nuts posts, which claimed that gc would allocate data on the heap when using the NewFoo idiom. I'll test this now.

Comment: Dave C's answer is part of it: reasonably often the constructor gets inlined. When you need to pinch allocations of something, a common pattern is `thing.Reset()` to reuse an empty `Thing` and a `sync.Pool` to manage them. Of course, you can then also use `f.Reset()` in place of `NewFoo(f)` in your construction, but that isn't idiomatic--I'd only do it if it led to a measurable improvement in a critical part of your program (like, a spot where a lot of garbage is generated, in a program where performance needs tuning and collection time is an important factor in that).

Comment: Though you asked a pretty reasonable q (behavior here isn't obvious), my general advice is to build the functionality you want, then measure and tune the fatty bits only when you have nothing better to do. Life's too precious to spend too much of it sweating processor cycles. :)

Comment: @two Of course. My issue was that I thought of a particular compiler optimization that could've been possible in Go but didn't know if this was even possible or if this exists. I am usually the first to try to prove myself wrong, but I couldn't come up with cases where the approach fails, and I couldn't find what I was looking for either, so I decided to ask on SO, because someone here might be able to prove me wrong or even point me in the right direction. In the end I still managed to find it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Not quite an answer but too big for a comment.)

From the comments it seems you might be interested in this small example:

```
package main

type Foo struct {
    i, j, k int
}

func NewFoo() *Foo {
    return &Foo{i: 42}
}

func F1() {
    f := NewFoo()
    f.i++
}

func main() {
    F1()
}
```

On Go1.5 running `go build -gcflags="-m"` gives:

```
./new.go:7: can inline NewFoo
./new.go:11: can inline F1
./new.go:12: inlining call to NewFoo
./new.go:16: can inline main
./new.go:17: inlining call to F1
./new.go:17: inlining call to NewFoo
./new.go:8: &Foo literal escapes to heap
./new.go:12: F1 &Foo literal does not escape
./new.go:17: main &Foo literal does not escape
```

So it inlines `NewFoo` into `F1` into `main` (and says that it could further inline `main` if someone was to call it).
Although it does say that in `NewFoo` itself `&Foo` escapes, it does *not* escape when inlined.

The output from `go build -gcflags="-m -S"` confirms this with a `main` initializing the object on the stack and not doing any function calls.

Of course this is a very simple example and any complications (e.g. calling `fmt.Print` with `f`) could easily cause it to escape.
In general, you shouldn't worry about this too much unless profiling has told you that you have a problem area(s) and you are trying to optimize a specific section of code.
Idiomatic and readable code should trump optimization.

Also note that using `go test -bench -benchmem` (or preferably using `testing.B`'s [`ReportAllocs`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B.ReportAllocs) method) can report on allocations of benchmarked code which can help identify something doing more allocations than expected/desired.

Comment: I am accepting this answer instead of my own because my question was arguably too broad and more about optimizing away heap allocations in cases like I mentioned instead of being specifically about optimizing it via RVO.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more research I found what I was looking for.

What I was describing is apparently called "Return value optimization" and is well doable, which pretty much answers my question about whether this was possible in Go as well.

Further information about this can be found here:
[What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)